# System.Windows.Ria.Controls and POCO

Tags: xaml, silverlight, poco

I'm trying to figure out how to use POCO for silverlight use.  I found an article that appears it will step me through  the basics.  However, it has in it a reference to the `System.Windows.Ria.Controls`. I don't have that on my machine.. I found System.Windows.Ria but not one that has the control on it.  I just downloaded the RIA beta today and installed it.. so should have the latest and greatest.  Anyway.. Here is the link to the article... [link text](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/05/silverlight-ria-services-and-your-business-objects.aspx)

And here is the code in the xaml they refer to.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Try1Silverlight.MainPage"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
 xmlns:riaControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Ria.Controls"
 xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:Try1Silverlight.Web"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource x:Name="CustomerSource"
                        QueryName="GetCustomers" AutoLoad="True">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <domain:CustomerContext/>
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

    <data:DataGrid x:Name="CustomerList"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=CustomerSource}">
    </data:DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What have I done wrong that the Ria.Control is not there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The System.Windows.Controls.Ria assembly has been replaced by this assembly:

```
System.Windows.Controls.DomainServices
```

You can find a list of the breaking changes with the v1.0 release of WCF RIA Services [right here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3570).

Comment: jvcoach23 and Andrew Garrison are 100% right. The assembly name had changed and do not apears in .Net references filtered to Silverlight 4 when use VS2010. Just browse for it manually ;)..

Answer (score 0):

well.. i figured it out... had to browse out to it in the add referrences.. was under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Silverlight

sorry about that
shannon